# Makefile/Cmake hide "conflicting types" error

Tags: makefile, cmake, clion

I am trying to compile a program in CLion and am getting the error "conflicting types" and "previous declaration of...".  This is because I have a function index() that is also in the string.h library.  I need this function to be named this for an assignment and am wondering if there is a way to hide this error with some cmake flag or something.

Comment: iiuic, putting your code in a namespace should solve your problem.

Comment: It could be many reasons of "conflicting types" error. Without viewing the code (in form of [mcve]) it is impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and have fixed it. Within the project directory inside CLion, I navigated to `cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/${ProjectName}.dir/flags.make`. Inside that file, I changed the `C_FLAGS = -O0 -std=gnu99` to `C_FLAGS = -O0 -std=c11`.

Additionally, I found that removing `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)` and replacing it with `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c11")` in the CMakeLists.txt resulted in the same outcome.

Comment: Deactivating C extensions via [`C_EXTENSIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_EXTENSIONS.html?highlight=c_standard) target property (or `CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS` for all targets) would be preferable. `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11) set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)`

Comment: @fabian I put what you suggested and that worked also.  Thanks.